# what is wrong in this mysql cursor, and how to correct it?

Tags: mysql, cursor, procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curLike()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE likeRec likecounttable;
        DECLARE c_likeCount CURSOR FOR SELECT l.likeCount, l.qId  FROM likecounttable l;

        OPEN c_likeCount;
        start_loop:LOOP
            FETCH c_likeCount IN likeRec
            UPDATE qentry SET qentry.likeCount = likeRec.likeCount WHERE qentry.qId=likeRec.qId;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_likeCount;
    END;
```

*I am trying to use a cursor here which fetches records from likecounttable, I saw this type of syntax in few sites so I used it but it is not working*

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: What error are you getting? What does it do or not do compared to what you expect it to do or not do?

Comment: first be clear about concepts of variable declaration and cursor syntax

Comment: Query: CREATE PROCEDURE curLike() BEGIN declare likeRec likecounttable DECLARE c_likeCount CURSOR FOR SELECT l.likeCount, l.qId FROM li...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'likecounttable
  DECLARE c_likeCount CURSOR FOR SELECT l.likeCount, l.qId  FROM ' at line 3


----It is showing this error

Actuall I have used cursors and all in Oracle a lot but in MySql it is first time for me. Please help me

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: yes I checked that answer, it is also working thanks for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semi-colon after your first declaration, furthermore, `likecounttable` is a table, not a data type.

Since you're trying to store two column values into your declared variables, your first line should look more like this

```
DECLARE likeRec_Count, likeRec_qId INT;
```

After reading your code, if you aren't adding to your cursor, you can simplify by using the following sql instead, which does the same thing as your cursor.

```
UPDATE qentry JOIN likecounttable l ON l.qId=qentry.qId
  SET qentry.likeCount = l.likeCount
;
```

**EDIT:** If you wanted a complete update to your cursor, the following should do the same thing.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE curLike()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE c_likeRec_isdone BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE likeRec_Count, likeRec_qId INT;
        DECLARE c_likeCount CURSOR FOR SELECT l.likeCount, l.qId  FROM likecounttable l;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET c_likeRec_isdone = TRUE;

        OPEN c_likeCount;
        loop_likeRecList: LOOP

           FETCH c_likeCount INTO likeRec_Count, likeRec_qId;
           IF c_likeRec_isdone THEN
              SET c_likeRec_isdone = FALSE;
              LEAVE loop_likeRecList;
           END IF;

           UPDATE qentry SET qentry.likeCount = likeRec_Count WHERE qentry.qId=likeRec_qId;

        END LOOP loop_likeRecList;
        CLOSE c_likeCount;
    END;
$$
```

Comment: yes this simple Sql query is solving the purpose for me thanks for that query.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curLike()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE likeRec_Count, likeRec_qId INT;
        DECLARE c_likeCount CURSOR FOR SELECT l.likeCount, l.qId  FROM likecounttable l;

        OPEN c_likeCount;
        start_loop:LOOP
            FETCH c_likeCount INTO likeRec_Count,likeRec_qId 
            UPDATE qentry SET qentry.likeCount = likeRec_Count WHERE qentry.qId=likeRec_qId ;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_likeCount;
    END;
```